# Check if a object is undeleteable

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, describesobject, describes

I want to check to see if a standard object is undeletable or not. I know there is a property that says isUndeleteable.

I can pull out the results with this code but I can't seem to figure out how to drill down into the specific property. I can see it in the debug but how do you get it into it's own thing so I can say something like if ____ is true do ____ else ___.

```
String[] types = new string[]{'OpportunityLineItem'};

Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);
System.debug('Results: ' + results);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) on `DescribeSObjectResult` shows a method called `isUndeletable()`:

```
for (DescribeSObjectResult result : results)
    system.debug(result.isUndeletable());
```

Or you can simply do:

```
Boolean isUndeletable = SObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.isUndeletable();
```

No need to use a list for just one item.